# Maze navigator AI

Tags: java, homework, pathfinding

I developed a maze navigator in Java for a project for my school. It works fine, and it gets through the maze just fine. The program prints to the screen each time it loops through the maze to set the next position. Note: there is only one path because I haven't implemented a multiple path algorithm yet. Is there any way to make this more elegant/efficient? The main things I'm looking to reduce are (if possible):

- Switch/Case Statements
- Memory (re-printing to the screen each time)
- Code Improvements that made the program more efficient/elegant

Any and all suggestions/improvements are welcome.

```
public class MazeAI {
    //maze layout below
    static int[][] maze = 
     {{1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1},
      {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1},
      {1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
      {1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
      {1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
      {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
      {1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
      {1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
      {1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
      {1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
      {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
      {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    };
    public static void main() {
        MazeAI m = new MazeAI();
        m.runAI(23,11); //where S is
    }

    void printMaze() {
        System.out.println("    MAZE     ");
        System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++) {
            String output = "";
            for(int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
                switch(maze[i][j]) {
                    case 0: output += " "; break;
                    case 1: output += "@"; break;
                    case 2: output += "S"; break;
                    case 3: output += "E"; break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(output);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }    

    void printPath(int[][] array, boolean last) {
        System.out.println("    PATH     ");
        System.out.println();
        if(last) {
            array[1][1] = 4;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            String output = "";
            for(int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
               switch(array[i][j]) {
                   case 0: output += " "; break;
                   case 1: output += "@"; break;
                   case 2: output += "S"; break;
                   case 3: output += "E"; break;
                   case 4: output += "^"; break;
                   case 5: output += "v"; break;
                   case 6: output += "<"; break;
                   case 7: output += ">"; break;
               }
            }
            System.out.println(output);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    void runAI(int i, int j) { //S is at (i,j) -> (9,11) | E is at (0,1)
        try { 
            printMaze(); 
            Thread.sleep(3000); 
            System.out.print('\f');
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int[][] arr = maze;
        int[] currentPos = {i,j};
        boolean running = true;
        while(running) {
            if(foundEnd(currentPos)) {
                running  = false;
                printPath(arr, true);
                break;
            }
            if(canMoveUp(arr, currentPos)) {
                arr[currentPos[0]][currentPos[1]] = 4;
                currentPos[0] -= 1;
            } else if(canMoveDown(arr, currentPos)) {
                arr[currentPos[0]][currentPos[1]] = 5;
                currentPos[0] += 1;
            } else if(canMoveLeft(arr, currentPos)) {
                arr[currentPos[0]][currentPos[1]] = 6;
                currentPos[1] -= 1;
            } else if(canMoveRight(arr, currentPos)) {
                arr[currentPos[0]][currentPos[1]] = 7;
                currentPos[1] += 1;
            }
            printPath(arr, false);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(150);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.print('\f');
        }
    }

    boolean canMoveUp(int[][] arr, int[] pos) {
        try {
            if(arr[pos[0] - 1][pos[1]] == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    boolean canMoveDown(int[][] arr, int[] pos) {
        try {
            if(arr[pos[0] + 1][pos[1]] == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    boolean canMoveRight(int[][] arr, int[] pos) {
        try {
            if(arr[pos[0]][pos[1] + 1] == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    boolean canMoveLeft(int[][] arr, int[] pos) {
        try {
            if(arr[pos[0]][pos[1] - 1] == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
            return false;
            }
        } catch (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    boolean foundEnd(int[] pos) {
        if(pos[0] == 1 && pos[1] == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You know about genetic algorithms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good job so far! I got some remarks, hopefully you'll find them useful.

### Try Different Algorithms :)

See this nice Wikipedia entry for a list of possible algorithms to solve a maze:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm

### Reuse code

This switch block appears 1.5 times in your code. Consider making it a method.

```
               case 0: output += " "; break;
               case 1: output += "@"; break;
               case 2: output += "S"; break;
               case 3: output += "E"; break;
               case 4: output += "^"; break;
               case 5: output += "v"; break;
               case 6: output += "<"; break;
               case 7: output += ">"; break;
```

### Remove unnecessary code

You use this:

```
   if(arr[pos[0]][pos[1] - 1] == 0) {
        return true;
   } else {
   return false;
   }
```

Which can be re-written to:

```
    return arr[pos[0]][pos[1] - 1] == 0;
```

Which is much clearer to me :)

### AIOOBE vs bounds check

You currently let the `canMove` throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Some consider this bad practice, because this is 'normal' flow. You should check before if your indices are valid.

### String concatenation

Try to prevent String concatenation by using the `+` operator. It creates many unnecessary intermediate objects.

See also here: https://redfin.engineering/java-string-concatenation-which-way-is-best-8f590a7d22a8

### Consider using char directly

Your memory-model model is an `int[][]`. Your code uses 'magic values' that test `int` values. `char` is also well-suited to use as values in your grid, and you can then directly print and test these `char` values. Constructing the grid can start from a list of `Strings` with `toCharArray()` and your maze in code looks exactly like the output on the console

(Or else, at least create readable constants for the `int`s in the  `if` statements)

### Consider coding the directions in an enum :

```
enum Direction {
  UP(0,-1), LEFT(-1,0), RIGHT(1,0), DOWN(0,1);

  int dx;
  int dy;

  Direction(dx, dy)
  {
     this.dx=dx;
     this.dy=dy;
  }
}

for (Direction d : Direction.values())
{
   if (canMove(arr, currentPos, direction))
   {
       markMove(arr, currentPos, direction);
   }
}
```

Something like this:

```
  boolean canMove(int[][] arr, int[] pos, Direction d) {
        try {
            return arr[pos[0] + d.dx][pos[1] + d.dy] == 0
        } catch (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```